# Spark RDD :How to share data for a parallel operation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

My understanding of spark is that when you run a reduce operation on RDD, its being operated in  parallel by different nodes and result is accumulated back by master node. Since these operation run in parallel , result is available as a whole and we can not rely on any update done in between during processing e.g say I am designing a shared cab app and I have a RDD which contains start location of trip and actual location of different cabs . I can easily run a spark sql to get the distance of each cab from trip start point. Once , I have this , I need to pick the shortest distance cab and allocate it. Now here we have a condition that a cab can not take more then 4 trips. Since my analysis is running in parallel, I can not be sure if already cab is full capacity. So what is the best way to validate this. Can we have a shared variable or should we store allocation in database. Performance is the key

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality as such in spark, you can make use of Apache Ignite 
[image: Ignite for Spark]
For more details refer link
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs

Comment: We can not jump to ignite as of now. I know its not possible in spark and that is the reason , we need to store it outside spark. My questions is what is the best practice for such scenario which has least impact on performance.